# CursorWrapper getNotificationUri back port

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

KitKat added the method getNotificationUri() to CursorWrapper. Is there a cleaner way of retrieving it on older API versions besides using reflection?

Answer (score 0):

Cursor is an interface. It depends on what implementation of Cursor you're using. Any Cursor derived from AbstractCursor supports [getNotificationUri at least since Android 4.0.1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/database/AbstractCursor.java#AbstractCursor.getNotificationUri%28%29). You just need to cast your Cursor into an AbstractCursor to be able to call getNotificationUri().

With older versions of Android (e.g. 2.3), that method doesn't exist in AbstractCursor. There *is* however a very dirty way of accessing it: *reflection*. The `Uri` you're looking for is stored in a private field named `mNotifyUri` ([line 634](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/database/AbstractCursor.java#634) in AbstractCursor). Reflection, especially used this way, is generally frowned upon, so I wouldn't recommend doing it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't write the question correctly. I am using CursorWrapper which didn't add getNotificationUri() until API 19. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWrapper.html#getNotificationUri()